# How to model availability in a simple hostel booking system? (Laravel 5)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I've got a simple hostel booking system and am not sure how to model availability in the database (e.g. via Eloquent). A hostel is simpler than a hotel as for booking purposes it's effectively just one big room. However there will be multiple hotels in the database (run by different owners). So my current database tables are: Guests, Hostels (includes owner details), Bookings (i.e. person W staying at hostel X from date Y to date Z), and Payments (payment amount for a stay). Obviously these are tied together (e.g. with ID references or some other relationship).

But with availability I need to represent the number of beds available for a specific hostel on any specific date(s) for e.g. the next year or two. What's an efficient way to do that?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: suppose user checkouts at 12.20 then what time the bed will be available @Alex is it hourly or date based booking system

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to model the an availability when you can make it simpler by querying if date is available then store it based in a specific hostel?

e.g:

1. You have a hostel.
2. In a calendar you show the dates that has been taken from arrival to departure date in that hostel.
3. Guest chose a dates and submit
4. Check if dates intersects in booked dates in that hostel.
5. If there is no intersection with any of the booked dates in that hostel then it is available.
6. Save it on database.

and If you want to represent a number of beds for a specific hostel that's what you need to model not the availability since specifying how many beds is used for informational purposes.

```
class HostelBed extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['count', 'from', 'to'];

    public function hostel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Hostel::class);
    } 
}
```

Query all the beds in a calendar then display it in your calendar or anywhere you want to.

Comment: Perhaps a guest is flexible about their dates.

Comment: suppose the user books the bed for 3 days then in your db you will enter start date and end date or all 3 days @jerico